# No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_SUB in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run this query in Google BigQuery,but

```
No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_SUB for argument types: DATETIME, INT64, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART) at [8:5]
```

This is the query:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION URL_DECODE(enc STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try { 
    return decodeURI(enc);;
  } catch (e) { return null }
  return null;
""";

select 
replace(JSON_EXTRACT(URL_DECODE(l.ed), '$.phone'),"\"","") as phone
from pixel_logs.full_logs l
where ev = 'user_authentication'
and ed not like '%filipe.ferminiano%'
AND TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), interval 60 minute) > timestamp
group by
phone
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CURRENT_DATETIME()` returns a `DATETIME` value, not a `TIMESTAMP`. Maybe you meant to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`?

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION URL_DECODE(enc STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try { 
    return decodeURI(enc);;
  } catch (e) { return null }
  return null;
""";

select 
replace(JSON_EXTRACT(URL_DECODE(l.ed), '$.phone'),"\"","") as phone
from pixel_logs.full_logs l
where ev = 'user_authentication'
and ed not like '%filipe.ferminiano%'
AND TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), interval 60 minute) > timestamp
group by
phone
;
```